# C# List - creating ranking from list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a populated `List<Players>` with `Player` objects like this:

```
class Player
{
    public string Name
    { get; set; }

    public int Points
    { get; set; }

    public string Rank
    { get; set; }

}
```

Based on `Points`, I would like to achieve a grouped sorted list like this:

```
Rank   Name   Points
1-3.   RRR    10
       CCC    10
       AAA    10
4-5.   YYY    8
       XXX    8
6.     ZZZ    7
7-8.   UUU    5
       QQQ    5
```

... and so on. So `Name` should not be a must for sorting.
Is this possible with LINQ?

**Edit 1:**

I have tried so far this:

```
    players.ForEach(x =>
    {
        int cnt = players.Count(y => y.Points == x.Points);
        int ind = players.FindIndex(y => y.Points == x.Points);
        x.Rank = (cnt == 1 ? (ind + 1).ToString() : (ind + 1).ToString() + "-" + (ind + cnt).ToString()) + ".";
    });
```

It's very messy, and the desired result is not like I would like. Each player with the score equal to the above should have `Rank` property `empty`.

**Edit 2:**

A more clean code to achieve the desired result is the following:

```
    players.ForEach(x =>
    {
        int cnt = players.Count(y => y.Points == x.Points);
        int ind = players.FindIndex(y => y.Points == x.Points);
        x.Rank = ind != players.IndexOf(x) ? string.Empty : $"{ind + 1}" + (cnt == 1 ? string.Empty : "-" + $"{ind + cnt}") + ".";
    });
```

Comment: @dymanoid If it's already answered I did not find it. I would like to point me to the answer or show me how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious. You are sorting by Points, and assigning Rank based on where in the sort order the item occurs (the first three have 10 points and are tied for first, the next two have 8 points and are tied for 4th, etc.).  Does it make sense for Rank to be a property player, or just something ephemeral that occurs because of the sorting

Comment: Your question was "Is this possible with LINQ?", And @dymanoid answered "Yes, this is possible".  Yeah, it's not the answer you wanted, but you may want to ask a different question to get the answer you want.

Comment: @Flydog57 the list I would like to get is used for a html table, so i thought it would be easier to get the value from a property.

Comment: @dymanoid It's OK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have edited your post and displayed an attempt to solve the problem I will help you out. Pass any collection of players into this function to get a new collection of players back in the format you have asked for.

Note: This function modifies the `Player` references in the `IEnumerable<Player>` passed in. If, for some reason you do not want this behaviour, simply replace `Player = player` with `Player = new Player { Name = player.Name, Points = player.Points }` to copy them.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static IEnumerable<Player> GetGroupedPlayers(IEnumerable<Player> players)
{
    return players
    .OrderByDescending(player => player.Points)
    .Select((player, index) =>
    new
    {
        Player = player,
        Rank = ++index
    })
    .GroupBy(container => container.Player.Points)
    .Select(group =>
    {
        var firstPlayer = group.First().Player;
        var groupMin = group.Min(container => container.Rank);
        var groupMax = group.Max(container => container.Rank);
        firstPlayer.Rank = groupMin == groupMax ? $"{groupMin}." : $"{groupMin} - {groupMax}.";
        return group.Select(g => g.Player);
    })
    .SelectMany(player => player);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! You provided a nice code showing the power of LINQ. In terms of benchmark, your approach runs 2-3 times slower than the upgraded version of my code. Nevertheless I think I should accept this as a valid answer. Is it true, @dymanoid?

Comment: More than happy to help. I assume your *upgraded version* of your code is achieving the same results without LINQ, is that correct?

Comment: see my *Edit 2:*.

Comment: Beware that, although *your upgraded version* gives you the desired result, it is **not** doing the same thing.

For a start, my approach will return the list of players ordered, yours won't this will of course involve some additional overhead).

As far as the comment about mine running *2-3 times slower*, this is only true with a small set of Players. If you operate both of these functions on a large set of players, yours will run **significantly** slower.

This is mainly due to all of the redundant enumerations through `players.Count()`, `players.FindIndex()`, and `players.IndexOf()`.

Comment: And it does! WIth large lists is way slower. Fortunately I need a list of max 15 players, so it's not a drawback. But... subsequent runs over new randomly generated lists (10 players) shows that your code is working genuinely better. Why is that? Some caching occures on the logic of LINQ? I can't explain it with my little knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication106
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             List<Player> players = new List<Player>() {
                 new Player() { Name = "RRR", Points = 10 },
                 new Player() { Name = "CCC", Points = 10 },
                 new Player() { Name = "AAA", Points = 10 },
                 new Player() { Name = "YYY", Points = 8 },
                 new Player() { Name = "XXX", Points = 8 },
                 new Player() { Name = "ZZZ", Points = 7 },
                 new Player() { Name = "UUU", Points = 5 },
                 new Player() { Name = "QQQ", Points = 5 }
             };

             var groups = players.OrderBy(x => x.Points)
                 .Select((x, i) => new { rank = i + 1, player = x })
                 .GroupBy(x => x.player.Points).Select(x => new { rank = x.Min(y => y.rank).ToString() + "-" + x.Max(y => y.rank).ToString(), players = x.ToList()})
                 .ToList();

             foreach (var group in groups)
             {
                 group.players.First().player.Rank = group.rank;

                 //foreach (var player in group.players)
                 //{
                 //    player.player.Rank = group.rank;
                 //}
             }
        }

    }
    class Player
    {
        public string Name
        { get; set; }

        public int Points
        { get; set; }

        public string Rank
        { get; set; }

    }



}
```

Comment: Please don't answer homework questions that show no effort. You're turning Stack Overflow into a code writing service.

Comment: @dymanoid You're right, but voting down an excellent answer is harsh ... would be better to just ask him.

Comment: How do you know it is homework and not something his boss needs?

Comment: Guys it's not for business, don't worry.

Comment: @jdweng not quite the result I expect. My edit gets the same result. I need empty *Rank* for consequent rankings. So first is 1-3, second and third player needs empty *Rank* property.

Comment: @jdweng, regardless of whether this is homework or a job assignment, answering a question "I NEED THIS, GIMME TEH CODEZ" turns Stack Overflow into a code writing service. Make sure you understand what Stack Overflow's mission is. Now, the OP edited their question providing some code and described the issues with that. It turned the question into an acceptable one, so now it can be of course answered.

Comment: I made a small change to give the desired results.

Comment: @dymanoid : Using you rules nobody will be able to get any help.  All those rules do is discourage people from learning.

Comment: @jdweng, these are not my rules, please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: The rules do not make any sense especially for novices who do not know enough to even ask the correct question.  People keeping on asking people who do not know what they are doing to write code that will not work is just a waste of time and is not productive.  Then asking people to search the web is again a waste of time because they do not know what words to use in the search.